# Same Dialog Box for Different ListItems

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

```py
for item in item_list:  //Item is a String
    self.ids.container.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=item,on_release=lambda e:self.open_msg(item)))

def open_msg(self,msg):
    self.dial = MDDialog(text=msg,buttons=[MDFlatButton(text="DISCARD")])
    self.dial.open()
```

[image]

If I should click an item, I should see it in Dialog Box, but even I click any List Item I get the value of last element.

[image]

I clicked on A but I received E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your lambda from:

```
lambda e:self.open_msg(item)
```

to:

```
lambda e, t=item:self.open_msg(t)
```